# Gitlab private token permission

Tags: curl, gitlab

Is it possible to check the scope / permissions of the private token that we connect to gitlab?
In the bash script I would like to check if I can create a branch with the token that I authorize.
This command only returns me a list of all tokens, and I would like to check what washing is the one that authorizes.

```
curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_TOKEN}" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/personal_access_tokens"
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to check the scopes that they were created with?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add some post-processing to your curl, after getting your GitLab token ID:

```
curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_TOKEN}" \
  "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/personal_access_tokens" | \
  jq '.[] | select(.id == ${GITLAB_TOKEN_ID}).scopes'
```